ActiveMQ Artemis HA 3-node configuration
I am creating an ActiveMQ Artemis HA configuration with 1 primary and 2 backups. However, only one backup is working. Two backups is not showing or activated. How I can trouble-shoot this or it is possible or not? I am using the shared storage.
I was trying to setup 2 backups and a primary server so that the 2 backups are active at a time. Is this possible or not? I am using the shared storage.

The details are somewhat unclear, but I believe what you're seeing is expected. A primary will only pair with one backup. Any other potential backup will remain in a kind of limbo state until the primary fails and the backup activates at which point the additional backup will pair with the now-active backup. See the documentation which states:

Each primary server can be paired with one backup server. Other backups can be configured, but the primary will only pair with one. When the primary fails the backup will take over. At this point if there are other backups configured then the backup that took over will pair with one of those.

Generally speaking I do not recommend using multiple backups as it doesn't provide any significant benefit over having just one backup.

In my current setup with 1 master and 2 backup brokers, I have observed that when the master is active, only one backup broker is in passive mode, while the other backup is not in passive. The second backup only activates if either the master or the first backup goes down. The console also shows one live broker and one backup, but I need both backup brokers to be in passive mode simultaneously. How can I achieve this configuration?

As noted in my answer, a primary will only pair with one backup. In other words, what you're seeing is the expected behavior, and that behavior can't be changed.

If you tell me one backup how will you prove it or is there any documetation..

I've been one of the main developers on ActiveMQ Artemis for more than a decade. Aside from that, the documentation says that a primary will only pair with one backup.

Thak you for your kind information..

I need a command to get artemis queue message timestamp using artemis cli

I don't really understand what you're asking. I recommend you create a new question since this doesn't appear directly related to this questions.
